# Determine Regression Coefficients with Least Square Means in SAS?

Tags: sas, regression, least-squares

If I have the following table of least square means estimates:

[image: Least Square Means]

can I compute regression coefficients for `x1`, `x2` and `x3` as follows:

- coefficient for `x1`: `b1` = 6.1426 - 8.1241
- coefficient for `x2`: `b2` = 4.2472-10.0195
- coefficient for `x3`: `b3` = 5.6045 - 8.6622

and then construct the model:`y = b1*x1 +b2*x2 +b3*x3 + mean(y)`? This is a `2^k` experimental design.

Comment: You've used a parameterization of -1 vs 1. I find this hard to rewrite the equation. If possible, consider the 0/1 parameterization method instead.

Comment: @Reeza If I coded the variables with 0 and 1 instead of -1 and 1 to denote the low and high levels, why would coefficients be different?

Comment: You can get the differences you show using DIFF LSMEANS statement option.

Comment: @Milos sorry, you're correct it doesn't. I am correct in assuming you have 3 levels for each of your variables?

Comment: @data_null_ thanks for the tip. ;)

Comment: @Reeza No, only two, it is a `2^3` design. There are three variables and each has two levels: one high and the other low.